# Create Dictionary from pandas Error:TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create list of dictionary from pandas dataframe. I keep getting this error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. 'name' col is string/object, why does it say 'integers'?

```
d = [{'name':[]}]
for row in my_df:
    print(row['name'])

print(my_df['name'].dtype)
>>> dtype('O')
```

Comment: you need to do *for index,row in my_df.iterrows():*

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `for` loop on a DataFrame, you get the column names - which are strings. The `integers` in the error means you can index str just with integers (to get a specifc byte)